# Calculate the binomial $(1-x)^{-(n+1)}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Calculate the binomial $(1-x)^{-(n+1)}$

What I have tried:

$$(1-x)^{-(n+1)} \implies (1-x)^{-1}(1-x)^{-n} \\
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x)^{k} \\
(1-x)^{-n} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-n}{k}(-x)^k \\
\implies (1-x)^{-(n+1)} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-n}{k}(-x)^k \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x)^{k}$$

However, I was wondering how I could get this form instead:
$$(1-x)^{-(n+1)} = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is more convenient to take $n+1$ as is which gives
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(1-x)^{-(n+1)}}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(n+1)}{k}(-x)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}{k}x^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{k+n}{n}x^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{n-k}x^{n-k}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we exchange $k$ and $n$.
- In (4) we shift the index to start with $n=k$.
- In (5) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.